Rooted but unable to setup WireGuard VPN on Termux
I have read WireGuard quickstart and successfully set up a connection between the server (Android 14, Google Pixel 7) and the client. But as for IP forwarding, after following How to enable IP forwarding in Android?, How can I enable ip_forward in Android? and How to get started with WireGuard VPN, it didn’t work.
Below is my setup commands on rooted pixel 7(Termux):
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
iptables -F -t filter
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

ip link add dev wg0 type wireguard
ip addr add dev wg0 192.168.2.1/24
wg setconf wg0 ./config.conf
ip link set dev wg0 up

and this is my config.conf
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
ListenPort = 53

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 192.168.2.2

Goal: to successfully set up the WireGuard VPN server as a proxy on Termux.
